# strace does not list /etc/hosts in ping/host command in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, dns, c

I was reading https://zwischenzugs.com/2018/06/08/anatomy-of-a-linux-dns-lookup-part-i/ and on the author's Debian/Ubuntu system `/etc/hosts` is used.

But when I do strace under CentOS 7, I don't see it.

For `host` command:

```
strace -e trace=open -f host google.com
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdns.so.100", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/liblwres.so.90", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libbind9.so.90", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libisccfg.so.90", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libisccc.so.90", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libisc.so.95", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libGeoIP.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libxml2.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/pki/tls/legacy-settings", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/libdns.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libdns.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/libdns.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libdns.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/libisc.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libisc.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/libisc.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libisc.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
strace: Process 3436 attached
strace: Process 3437 attached
strace: Process 3438 attached
[pid  3435] open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/libdst.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3435] open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/libdst.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3435] open("/usr/share/locale/en/libdst.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3435] open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/libdst.cat", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
[pid  3435] open("/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid  3435] open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY) = 6
[pid  3435] open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 6
google.com has address 172.217.164.142
```

For `ping` command:

```
strace -e trace=open -f ping -c1 google.com
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libidn.so.11", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libcrypto.so.10", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib64/libz.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/pki/tls/legacy-settings", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
PING google.com (172.217.15.78) 56(84) bytes of data.
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
64 bytes from iad23s63-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.15.78): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=1.68 ms
```

I am told, according the author, that each tool (`host`, `ping`, `getent`, `nslookup`) perhaps uses different API.

`/etc/hosts.conf`

```
multi on
```

`/etc/nsswtich.conf`

```
hosts:      files dns myhostname
```

Comment: I think as [host(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/host) is specifically for DNS lookups it wouldn't make sense for it to check the `/etc/hosts` file

Comment: What do your nsswitch.conf and host.conf contain?

Comment: Thanks. Updated.

Comment: What's the output of `service nscd status` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`host`, `nslookup` and `dig` are all DNS utilities: they do DNS queries, and hence bypass the nornal name resolution provided by OS/libc through usual `gethostbyname()` and `getaddrinfo()` calls.

Note that they still use `/etc/resolv.conf` themselves as a kind of bootstrap: to know which server to contact in case you do not provide one (and it is mostly always preferable to specify which nameserver you query with these tools as normal DNS troubleshooting often starts by querying authoritative nameservers then only recursive ones, which is the kind of the ones stored in `/etc/resolv.conf`).

`ping` is almost the wrong tool for any kind of troubleshooting, but regarding its name resolution needs it uses the standard tools given by OS/libc which will dictate how the name resolution occurs, if it is with the DNS, a local file, LDAP, NIS, mDNS, or any other source of information. This is the role of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.
And hence you will see it open the files:

```
# strace -e open ping -c 1 www.example.com
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
PING www.example.com (93.184.216.34) 56(84) bytes of data.
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
64 bytes from 93.184.216.34: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=1.00 ms

--- www.example.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.003/1.003/1.003/0.000 ms
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

`getent` is a generic utility to query information from sources of data listed in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. So you have the `ahosts` and `hosts` "databases" that you can use `getent` with. The call will or will not use the DNS, depending on the content of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, and the content of `/etc/hosts` if `files` is listed as source for these databases.

```
# strace -e open getent ahostsv4 www.example.com
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/UTF-8/LC_CTYPE", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 3
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
93.184.216.34   STREAM www.example.com
93.184.216.34   DGRAM
93.184.216.34   RAW
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

You can even infer that it does first check `/etc/hosts` because it opens `libnss_files` first and with this configuration, as no entry found, it falls back to the DNS thanks to `libnss_dns`.

PS: note also that `/etc/gai.conf` may be used when it is the OS/libc that handles the name resolution, as it defines the order of IP addresses (and typically if IPv6 is to be preferred over IPv4 or the opposite), which comes into play for hosts having multiple addresses of one or more address families.